# Help error message inside dynamic T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, index, dynamic-sql, automation

I have a requirement to come up with reporting for indexes for our whole production environment:

I found the below script online and modified it according to my requirement and trying to execute it using cursor (I have also tried sp_MSForEachDb) to get result from all databases in the instance.  The script should show all Exact Duplicate indexes in a particular database.

Although I have wrapped my query in double quotes but I keep getting too many errors.

If I run the script without loop it returns the result correctly.

Please see the script and errors I'm getting below the script. I have been struggling with this for the past few days and have looked exhaustively online [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37440964/running-a-large-t-sql-query-on-all-databases)  and many other posts but can;t figure this out.

I will need to send the result in email body to our distribution list for all servers. so, I will appreciate if someone has a better idea on how to establish this.

Script:

```
DECLARE @db_name AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') and state <> 1

OPEN c_db_names

FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IndexTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #IndexTemp --If exist drop the temp table. 
  EXEC('
   Begin
   USE ' + '[' + @db_name + ']' + '

                        ;WITH CTE_INDEX_DATA AS (
                       SELECT
                              SCHEMA_DATA.name AS schema_name,
                              TABLE_DATA.name AS table_name,
                              INDEX_DATA.name AS index_name,
                              STUFF((SELECT  '', '' + COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.name + '' '' + CASE WHEN INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ''DESC'' ELSE ''ASC'' END -- Include column order (ASC / DESC)
                                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id
                                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_included_column = 0
                                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.key_ordinal
                                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS key_column_list ,
                          STUFF(( SELECT  '', '' + COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.name
                                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id
                                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.is_included_column = 1
                                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.key_ordinal
                                                  FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS include_column_list,
                       INDEX_DATA.is_disabled -- Check if index is disabled before determining which dupe to drop (if applicable)
                       FROM sys.indexes INDEX_DATA
                       INNER JOIN sys.tables TABLE_DATA
                       ON TABLE_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA.object_id
                       INNER JOIN sys.schemas SCHEMA_DATA
                       ON SCHEMA_DATA.schema_id = TABLE_DATA.schema_id
                       WHERE TABLE_DATA.is_ms_shipped = 0
                       AND INDEX_DATA.type_desc IN (''NONCLUSTERED'', ''CLUSTERED'')
                ) 

                --Insert all records into a temp table #IndexTemp with appropriate filters:
                SELECT * INTO #IndexTemp
                FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE1
                WHERE EXISTS
                (SELECT * FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE2
                 WHERE DUPE1.schema_name = DUPE2.schema_name
                 AND DUPE1.table_name = DUPE2.table_name
                 AND DUPE1.key_column_list = DUPE2.key_column_list
                 AND ISNULL(DUPE1.include_column_list, '') = ISNULL(DUPE2.include_column_list, '')
                 AND DUPE1.index_name <> DUPE2.index_name)
                 AND INDEX_NAME NOT LIKE (''%PK%'')

                --Return duplicate tbale_names only 
                 SELECT * from #IndexTemp WHERE table_name IN
                    (SELECT table_name FROM #IndexTemp GROUP BY table_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
                    ORDER BY table_name

   END')
  FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

For each database, I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
>   
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 38
>   
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.
>   
> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
>   
> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'AND'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with [Erik](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249521/22336), but answering your question the error was in the quotation marks in the STUFF and here AND ISNULL (DUPE1.include_column_list, '') = ISNULL (DUPE2.include_column_list, '')

You did not have the quotation marks correctly, remember that when you intermix texts all the '' must be like '' ''

```
DECLARE @db_name AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE c_db_names CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name NOT IN('master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb') and state <> 1 

OPEN c_db_names

FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#IndexTemp') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #IndexTemp --If exist drop the temp table. 
  EXEC('
   Begin
   USE ' + '[' + @db_name + ']' + '

                        ;WITH CTE_INDEX_DATA AS (
                       SELECT
                              SCHEMA_DATA.name AS schema_name,
                              TABLE_DATA.name AS table_name,
                              INDEX_DATA.name AS index_name,
                              STUFF((SELECT  '', '' + COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.name + '' '' + CASE WHEN INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ''DESC'' ELSE ''ASC'' END -- Include column order (ASC / DESC)
                                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.column_id
                                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_KEY_COLS.index_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.is_included_column = 0
                                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_KEY_COLS.key_ordinal
                                                  FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 2, '''') AS key_column_list ,--BAD quotation 
                          STUFF(( SELECT  '', '' + COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.name
                                                  FROM    sys.tables AS T
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.indexes INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.index_columns INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id = INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                                INNER JOIN sys.columns COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS
                                                                ON T.object_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id = COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.column_id
                                                  WHERE   INDEX_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.object_id
                                                                AND INDEX_DATA.index_id = INDEX_DATA_INC_COLS.index_id
                                                                AND INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.is_included_column = 1
                                                  ORDER BY INDEX_COLUMN_DATA_INC_COLS.key_ordinal
                                                  FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 2, '''') AS include_column_list,--BAD quotation 
                       INDEX_DATA.is_disabled -- Check if index is disabled before determining which dupe to drop (if applicable)
                       FROM sys.indexes INDEX_DATA
                       INNER JOIN sys.tables TABLE_DATA
                       ON TABLE_DATA.object_id = INDEX_DATA.object_id
                       INNER JOIN sys.schemas SCHEMA_DATA
                       ON SCHEMA_DATA.schema_id = TABLE_DATA.schema_id
                       WHERE TABLE_DATA.is_ms_shipped = 0
                       AND INDEX_DATA.type_desc IN (''NONCLUSTERED'', ''CLUSTERED'')
                ) 

                --Insert all records into a temp table #IndexTemp with appropriate filters:
                SELECT * INTO #IndexTemp
                FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE1
                WHERE EXISTS
                (SELECT * FROM CTE_INDEX_DATA DUPE2
                 WHERE DUPE1.schema_name = DUPE2.schema_name
                 AND DUPE1.table_name = DUPE2.table_name
                 AND DUPE1.key_column_list = DUPE2.key_column_list
                 AND ISNULL(DUPE1.include_column_list, '''') = ISNULL(DUPE2.include_column_list, '''') --BAD quotation 
                 AND DUPE1.index_name <> DUPE2.index_name)
                 AND INDEX_NAME NOT LIKE (''%PK%'')

                --Return duplicate tbale_names only 
                 SELECT * from #IndexTemp WHERE table_name IN
                    (SELECT table_name FROM #IndexTemp GROUP BY table_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
                    ORDER BY table_name

   END')
  FETCH c_db_names INTO @db_name
END

CLOSE c_db_names
DEALLOCATE c_db_names
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather than hack away at a script you don't understand well enough to troubleshoot, why not use something tested and understandable, like [sp_BlitzIndex](http://firstresponderkit.org)?

If you run `EXEC sp_BlitzIndex @Mode = 4, @GetAllDatabases = 1;` it will go through and diagnose all sorts of index issues beyond what you're looking for in that Script You Found On The Internet™